# How to write an array to text file ?VHDL code

Tags: vhdl, fpga, hdl

I want to write an image array to text file when i try the result is one column which contain all values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build up each line in the format you want, then write the whole line to file. There are suitable functions to help in the `std.textio` library.

Comment: how i can write the whole line at  one line  to the file

Comment: I think the function to do it is in std.text_io, called WriteLine.